# Ksoap backward result

Tags: android, soap, ksoap

I have ksop request.
what i knead to produce is

```
<ns4:senddata>
        <connectionId xsi:type="xsd:string">
      asdfdsafdsfasdfdsa
        </connectionId> 
        <tws xsi:type="ns4:tws">
            <message xsi:type="xsd:string">
                this test message with a message id
            </message>
            <messageId>123</messageId>
            <num xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" 
                     SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[3]" 
                     SOAP-ENC:offset="[0]">
                <item xsi:type="xsd:string">977</item>
                <item xsi:type="xsd:string">496</item>
            </num>
        </tws>
    </ns4:senddata>
```

and what i get is

```
<senddata xmlns= WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE >
        <tws>
            <num>
                <item xsi:type="xsd:string">977</item>
                <item xsi:type="xsd:string">496</item>
            </num>
            <message i:type="d:string">
                this test message with a message id
            </message>
            <messageId>123</messageId>
        </tws>
        <connectionId xsi:type="d:string">
      asdfdsafdsfasdfdsa
        </connectionId> 
    </senddata>
```

as you see the connectionID is at the bottom not the top.

```
private class smsSendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
String reSultstr = null;
for (String url : urls) {
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, url);
   request.addProperty("connectionId", did);

         SoapObject tws= new SoapObject("", "tws2");
     tws.addProperty("message", "message contents");
     tws.addProperty("messageId", "123");

       SoapObject num= new SoapObject("SOAP-ENC:Array", "mobiles");
    num.addProperty("item", "496");
          num.addProperty("item", "977");
          tws.addSoapObject(num);
    request.addSoapObject(tws);

      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
   HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    try {
        httpTransport.debug = true;
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                    reSultstr = response.getProperty(0).toString();
        } 
    catch (Exception exception){
       reSultstr = exception.toString();
       }
    }
    return reSultstr;
   }
```

I am using Ksoap2 2.5.8
if i switch to  2.6.* it just fatal error before it sends the request.
can someone see what is wrong.
I have two other ksop request and all is fine but this one has the extra tws node and i belive the problem is that the ConnectionId kneads to come first.

Comment: HI John,
I am facing same problem in access of WCF Web service in which have DataContantSeriliazation type xml. Can you help me if you have some few time.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Happy to help but could not fix my problem and have abandoned it. however the backward result i was having in this comment has been fixed by the creators of KSOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ksoap issue.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=113